# Highcharts xAxis points are not evenly distributed

Tags: highcharts

So this is my current demo - http://jsfiddle.net/use9mdwz/

A bunch of events happen within one minute or so and then the final event happens a few minutes later which makes the point distribution uneven.

The dates in my set are iso 8601 ie "2023-01-19T01:25:31.749Z" and converted to milliseconds `new Date(dateFormat).getTime()`

If I do not convert the dates the chart actually looks alright - http://jsfiddle.net/8u42bLwg/ but I am loosing the dates on the X axis.

How can I make it look like on the second demo but with proper timestamps?

Answer (score 0):

You can use category axis type and format labels in the way you want. For example:

```
xAxis: {
  type: 'category',
  labels: {
    // format: '{value:%Y-%m-%d}',
    formatter: function() {
      const date = new Date(this.value);
      const datevalues = [
        date.getFullYear(),
        date.getMonth() + 1,
        date.getDate(),
        date.getHours(),
        date.getMinutes(),
        date.getSeconds()
      ];

      return `${datevalues[3]}:${datevalues[4]}:${datevalues[5]}<br> ${datevalues[2]}-${datevalues[1]}-${datevalues[0]}`
    }
  }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/jsyu1q04/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.type

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/axes#axis-types